# Does there exist a function $f$ continiously differentiable on $[0,2]$?

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist a  function $f$  continiously differentiable  on $[0,2]$  and such that $f(0) = f(2) = 1,$ $|f'(x) | \le  1$    for  $x \in  [0,2]$   and $|\int_{0}^{2} f(x) dx | \le 1 ?$

My attempt  :  Yes , I was thinking about  this  function $f(x)=\sin ( x + \frac{\pi}{2} )$

Is its true ?

Comment: As written, your suggested function of $f(x)=\sin ( x + \frac{\pi}{2} )$ doesn't satisfy the requirement of $f(2) = 1$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan $\sin ( \frac{4 + \pi}{2} ) = 1$

Comment: @jasmine No, that is not true, $\sin(\frac{4+\pi}2) \neq 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $|f'(x)| \leq 1$ on $(0,2)$. We have by the mean value property that $|f(x)- f(0)| \leq x$ for every $x \in [0,1]$ and $|f(x) - f(2)| \leq 2-x$ for every $x \in [1,2]$.

In particular, because of the constraints $f(0) = f(2) = 1$, applying triangle inequality gives that $f(x) \geq |1-x|$ on $[0,2]$. Integrate both sides, check when equality applies ,and finish it from here.